# Ansible doesn't show tasks when including task file use "with_" loop

Tags: task, ansible

In ansible 2.1 there is loop_control feature that allow to use task `includes` + `with_` loop and pass loop item variable to its tasks. Before run playbook, I use to check list tasks. But when use  `with_` loop + task `include`, I can't check list tasks inside include file. Currently I'm using ansible 2.1.2.0 and here is my code:

main.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    var1:
      - 1
      - 2
  tasks:
  - name: debuging 1
    debug: msg=debug1
  - include: task1.yml var1=test1
    with_items: "{{ var1 }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: var2
  - name: debuging 2
    debug: msg=debug2
```

task1.yml

```
- name: "task1-1"
  debug: msg=task1-1
- name: "task1-2"
  debug: msg=task1-2
```

run ansible

```
$ ansible-playbook main1.yml -vv --list-tasks
No config file found; using defaults
1 plays in playbooks/main1.yml

playbook: playbooks/main1.yml

play #1 (localhost): localhost  TAGS: []
  tasks:
    debuging 1  TAGS: []
    include TAGS: []
    debuging 2  TAGS: []
```

Moreover when I apply tags on tasks, it will make more difficult to verify the playbook because it can't be shown. I think, it's good if ansible can also list all task inside task `include` files as if task include without `with_` loop. I expect that the output looks like

```
...
play #1 (localhost): localhost  TAGS: []
  tasks:
    debuging 1  TAGS: []
    tasks1-1    TAGS: []
    tasks1-2    TAGS: []
    debuging 2  TAGS: []
...
```

I don't know whether it's bug or not

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is an expected behavior. Please read [Dynamic versus Static Includes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#dynamic-versus-static-includes).

Excerpt from that chapter:

> When using dynamic includes, it is important to keep these limitations in mind:
>   - You cannot use notify to trigger a handler name which comes from a dynamic include.
>   - You cannot use --start-at-task to begin execution at a task inside a dynamic include.
>   - Tags which only exist inside a dynamic include will not show up in –list-tags output.
>   - Tasks which only exist inside a dynamic include will not show up in –list-tasks output.